# How do you download the iOS 10 Documentation in Xcode 8 GM Release?

Tags: ios, xcode8

Cannot seem to find where the documentation is location or where to download it if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to download it anymore. It's now included in the SDKs.

Source: [WWDC 2016 - Platforms State of the Union](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/102/?time=2345)

Comment: I don't see it in the Application folder or the Developer folders

Comment: You find it in Xcode: "Window" -> "Documentation and API Reference" http://imgur.com/a/AfpMt

Comment: I want the actual files though so I can add them to Dash

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of Dash adds support for reading the docs directly from XCode https://blog.kapeli.com/dash-3-dot-4